# Leiningen can't locate local dependency

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm having problems using a local version of a library which I don't want to push up to Clojars to test and find out it's broken. I appreciate this is a common problem for lots of devs new to Clojure and Leiningen. I've followed the steps provided by others and it still doesn't work.

**In summary**:
I've tried `lein pom/jar/install`, as well as the `checkout` feature (where you symlink your other project). I think there is a `source-paths` option I could try, but I'm not sure how that works. I also thought about trying to modify the `lein classpath` but I'm not sure if that's possible?

---

For those of you who prefer much more detail...

I have two Leiningen projects:

1. https://github.com/Integralist/spurious-clojure-aws-sdk-helper
2. https://github.com/Integralist/spurious-clojure-example

The idea is that the second project "spurious-clojure-example" should use the first "spurious-clojure-aws-sdk-helper" as a dev dependency (as it's a library you use while local dev'ing against faked AWS resources; so no need to use it in a production environment).

The "spurious-clojure-example" `project.clj` file looks like...

```
(defproject spurious-clojure-example "0.1.0"
  :description "This is an example application that utilises the Spurious Clojure AWS SDK Helper"
  :url "https://github.com/integralist/spurious-clojure-example"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [ring-server "0.3.1"]
                 [amazonica "0.3.13"]
                 [environ "1.0.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.12"]
            [lein-environ "1.0.0"]]
  :ring {:handler spurious-clojure-example.handler/app
         :init spurious-clojure-example.handler/init
         :destroy spurious-clojure-example.handler/destroy}
  :profiles
  {:uberjar {:aot :all}
   :production
   {:ring
    {:open-browser? false, :stacktraces? false, :auto-reload? false}}
   :dev
   {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"]
                   [ring/ring-devel "1.3.1"]
                   [spurious-aws-sdk-helper "0.1.0"]]}})
```

Notice I've put `[spurious-aws-sdk-helper "0.1.0"]` into `:dev {:dependencies}`.

The way the "spurious-clojure-aws-sdk-helper" code gets loaded is like so:

```
(if (env :debug) ; defined in profiles.clj
  (do
    (require '[spurious-aws-sdk-helper.core :as core])
    (...other stuff...)))
```

The first thing I tried within my "spurious-aws-sdk-helper" project was...

```
lein pom
lein jar
lein install
```

...as I was told this would install "spurious-aws-sdk-helper" into the local directory `~/.m2` which Leiningen would look at first as a local cache of remote dependencies.

```
tree ~/.m2 | grep spurious
├── spurious-aws-sdk-helper
│   └── spurious-aws-sdk-helper
│       │   ├── spurious-aws-sdk-helper-0.1.0.jar
│       │   └── spurious-aws-sdk-helper-0.1.0.pom
│       │   ├── spurious-aws-sdk-helper-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       │   └── spurious-aws-sdk-helper-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
├── spurious-clojure-example
│   └── spurious-clojure-example
│       │   ├── spurious-clojure-example-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       │   └── spurious-clojure-example-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

This didn't work. When I connect my Vim editor to an nREPL and try to evaluate the `require` call to the library it would say it couldn't find the namespace.

I then tried doing the same `lein pom/jar/install` process for my "spurious-clojure-example" project (just in case there was some strange reason both projects needed to be locally installed). Again, no difference either, but i wasn't expected this to do anything really.

I then tried renaming my projects to remove the `-SNAPSHOT` from the version number (in case that made Leiningen think the dependency couldn't be used - nonsense I know, but I was clutching at straws).

I moved onto trying out the `checkout` feature (https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies) and when I evaluated the `require` call, that would pass through (e.g. no errors) but then one of the dependencies used by "spurious-aws-sdk-helper" would fail to load (i.e. `org.clojure/data.json`).

As a temporary measure I decided to add `org.clojure/data.json` to my "spurious-clojure-example" dependencies. So when evaluating the code again in the REPL, it this time got past the first two namespace errors but then it again errored because the `spurious-aws-sdk-helper.s3` namespace couldn't be found :-/

At this point I realised I must be missing something really obvious, because it should not be this hard to test a library locally on your computer.

Could someone help me to resolve this problem.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE**: here is the result of `lein classpath` for "spurious-clojure-example"...

```
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/test
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/src
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/dev-resources
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/resources
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/target/classes
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ns-tracker/ns-tracker/0.2.1/ns-tracker-0.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.macro/0.1.0/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/algo.generic/0.1.2/algo.generic-0.1.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/java.classpath/0.2.0/java.classpath-0.2.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/watchtower/watchtower/0.1.1/watchtower-0.1.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-config/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-config-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-redshift/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.3/clojure-complete-0.2.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-glacier/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-glacier-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-directconnect/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-directconnect-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-codec/1.0.0/ring-codec-1.0.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-time-2.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-continuation-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lambda/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-lambda-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-storagegateway/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-storagegateway-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clj-stacktrace/clj-stacktrace/0.2.5/clj-stacktrace-0.2.5.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-opsworks/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-opsworks-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-servlet/1.2.1/ring-servlet-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clj-time/clj-time/0.4.4/clj-time-0.4.4.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-logs/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-logs-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/robert/hooke/1.3.0/hooke-1.3.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-simpledb/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudfront/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudfront-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-codedeploy/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-codedeploy-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/amazon-kinesis-client/1.1.0/amazon-kinesis-client-1.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-jetty-adapter/1.2.1/ring-jetty-adapter-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-support/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-support-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3/commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/hiccup/hiccup/1.0.5/hiccup-1.0.5.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/0.7.3/tools.reader-0.7.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring-refresh/ring-refresh/0.1.2/ring-refresh-0.1.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-rds/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-rds-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-importexport/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-importexport-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudformation/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-route53-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring/1.2.1/ring-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.namespace/0.1.3/tools.namespace-0.1.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.2/jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticache/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elasticache-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.3/snappy-0.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-devel/1.2.1/ring-devel-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-emr/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-emr-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clout/clout/1.1.0/clout-1.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.6/tools.nrepl-0.2.6.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-iam/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-iam-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-datapipeline/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-datapipeline-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/2.5.0.v201103041518/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-sns-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/environ/environ/1.0.0/environ-1.0.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/net/jpountz/lz4/lz4/1.2.0/lz4-1.2.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.2/jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/compojure/compojure/1.1.6/compojure-1.1.6.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring-server/ring-server/0.3.1/ring-server-0.3.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/taoensso/nippy/2.7.0/nippy-2.7.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/amazonica/amazonica/0.3.13/amazonica-0.3.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.2.1/ring-core-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-io-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-http-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.incubator/0.1.0/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/taoensso/encore/1.11.2/encore-1.11.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitosync/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cognitosync-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar
```

**UPDATE 2**:

```
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2
└── repository
    ├── amazonica
    ├── ant
    ├── antlr
    ├── aopalliance
    ├── args4j
    ├── asm
    ├── bbc
    ├── bidi
    ├── bouncycastle
    ├── ch
    ├── cheshire
    ├── circleci
    ├── classworlds
    ├── clj-stacktrace
    ├── clj-time
    ├── clojure-complete
    ├── clout
    ├── co
    ├── com
    ├── commons-beanutils
    ├── commons-cli
    ├── commons-codec
    ├── commons-collections
    ├── commons-digester
    ├── commons-discovery
    ├── commons-el
    ├── commons-fileupload
    ├── commons-httpclient
    ├── commons-io
    ├── commons-jelly
    ├── commons-jexl
    ├── commons-lang
    ├── commons-logging
    ├── commons-net
    ├── commons-validator
    ├── compojure
    ├── compojure-app
    ├── crypto-equality
    ├── crypto-random
    ├── de
    ├── dom4j
    ├── dotenv
    ├── doxia
    ├── environ
    ├── findbugs
    ├── geronimo-spec
    ├── hiccup
    ├── http-kit
    ├── instaparse
    ├── jackmorrill
    ├── javax
    ├── jaxen
    ├── jdom
    ├── jfree
    ├── jline
    ├── joda-time
    ├── junit
    ├── juxt
    ├── lein-dotenv
    ├── lein-environ
    ├── lein-ring
    ├── leinjacker
    ├── local
    ├── log4j
    ├── medley
    ├── modular
    ├── mx4j
    ├── nekohtml
    ├── net
    ├── ns-tracker
    ├── org
    ├── oro
    ├── pathetic
    ├── plexus
    ├── potemkin
    ├── prismatic
    ├── qdox
    ├── ring
    ├── ring-mock
    ├── ring-refresh
    ├── ring-server
    ├── robert
    ├── spurious-aws-sdk-helper
    ├── stax
    ├── thneed
    ├── tigris
    ├── trammel
    ├── velocity
    ├── watchtower
    ├── xalan
    ├── xerces
    ├── xml-apis
    ├── xom
    └── xpp3

95 directories, 0 files
```

**UPDATE 3**: `lein with-profile +dev classpath`

```
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/test
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/src
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/dev-resources
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/resources
/Users/markmcdonnell/Code/spurious-clojure-example/target/classes
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ns-tracker/ns-tracker/0.2.1/ns-tracker-0.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.macro/0.1.0/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/algo.generic/0.1.2/algo.generic-0.1.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/java.classpath/0.2.0/java.classpath-0.2.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/watchtower/watchtower/0.1.1/watchtower-0.1.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-config/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-config-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-redshift/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.3/clojure-complete-0.2.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-glacier/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-glacier-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-directconnect/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-directconnect-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-codec/1.0.0/ring-codec-1.0.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-time-2.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-continuation-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lambda/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-lambda-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-storagegateway/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-storagegateway-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clj-stacktrace/clj-stacktrace/0.2.5/clj-stacktrace-0.2.5.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-opsworks/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-opsworks-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-servlet/1.2.1/ring-servlet-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clj-time/clj-time/0.4.4/clj-time-0.4.4.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-logs/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-logs-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/robert/hooke/1.3.0/hooke-1.3.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-simpledb/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudfront/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudfront-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-codedeploy/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-codedeploy-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/amazon-kinesis-client/1.1.0/amazon-kinesis-client-1.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-jetty-adapter/1.2.1/ring-jetty-adapter-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-support/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-support-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3/commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/hiccup/hiccup/1.0.5/hiccup-1.0.5.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/0.7.3/tools.reader-0.7.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring-refresh/ring-refresh/0.1.2/ring-refresh-0.1.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-rds/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-rds-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-importexport/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-importexport-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudformation/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-route53-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring/1.2.1/ring-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.namespace/0.1.3/tools.namespace-0.1.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.2/jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticache/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elasticache-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.3/snappy-0.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-devel/1.2.1/ring-devel-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-emr/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-emr-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/clout/clout/1.1.0/clout-1.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.6/tools.nrepl-0.2.6.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-iam/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-iam-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-datapipeline/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-datapipeline-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/2.5.0.v201103041518/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-sns-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/environ/environ/1.0.0/environ-1.0.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/net/jpountz/lz4/lz4/1.2.0/lz4-1.2.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.2/jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/compojure/compojure/1.1.6/compojure-1.1.6.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring-server/ring-server/0.3.1/ring-server-0.3.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/taoensso/nippy/2.7.0/nippy-2.7.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/amazonica/amazonica/0.3.13/amazonica-0.3.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.2.1/ring-core-1.2.1.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-io-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-http-7.6.8.v20121106.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.incubator/0.1.0/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/taoensso/encore/1.11.2/encore-1.11.2.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitosync/1.9.13/aws-java-sdk-cognitosync-1.9.13.jar
/Users/markmcdonnell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Justin Smith from the #clojure irc channel helped me to resolve this issue.

It seems that just running `lein install` was enough, but the real issue was that the error I was seeing about the namespace not being found was actually misleading as there were errors within my helper library that needed to be fixed first before I could load it successfully in my example application.

The advice was to test thoroughly within the REPL (e.g. attempt to load the helper namespace within the helper's own REPL and if it doesn't work then run a linter to verify there is no issues with the code itself).

Comment: While I had done this before (as part of the sequence `lein pom, lein jar, lein install`), running `lein install` by itself, observing the file name that was output, updating my project.clj file to ensure the dependency matched the output of lein install, and then running `lein ring server` got things going for me. Not sure why it worked this way, but it did, so points to you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

`lein install` is the correct approach, but you must have some inconsistency in naming or versions.

It can be helpful to show the classpath that leiningen is actually using:

`lein classpath`

Or with a profile (the +dev means default +dev):

`lein with-profile +dev classpath`

You should find the library somewhere under ~/.m2 listed in the output.

`lein deps :tree` is similar and you may find it easier to find the inconsistency via that.

Comment: It seems if I run `lein deps :tree` I see that it doesn't mention `spurious-aws-sdk-helper` at all. Not sure why. If I run `lein ring server` I get a long Java stack trace error, but it's fundamentally around a dependency *within* the helper that's not found: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/data/json__init.class or clojure/dat
a/json.clj on classpath: , compiling:(spurious_aws_sdk_helper/utils.clj:1:1)`

Comment: I'll update the question above with the classpath now

Comment: In the classpath it shows the spurious helper, but that's because of the `checkout` symlink thing I was trying to get working

Comment: So, I removed spurious from `~/.m2` and removed the `checkouts` symlink stuff from "spurious-clojure-example". I then again ran `lein pom|jar|install` for "spurious-clojure-aws-sdk-helper" so it's back in `~/.m2`. Now if I run `lein ring server` I get a diff Java error: `Could not locate spurious_aws_sdk_helper/core__init.class or 
spurious_aws_sdk_helper/core.clj on classpath:`

Comment: I even tried using https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate as a way to dynamically modify the CLASSPATH at runtime, but when adding that as a main dependency and then running `lein deps` and `lein repl` it could not locate the pomegranate class :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had essentially the same issue, could not deal with it for 1.5 days... 
The solution involved:

1. Getting the groupid/artifactid dependancies right in all `project.clj` files and in the namespace declarations.
2. There was an unused test file in the library project that had a reference to another charting library which was not declared in the `project.clj` file. The project compiled and installed without this charting lib declaration. However, referencing this lib using the local repo did not work until I removed this test file (or included the needed charting lib dependency in its `project.clj`)
3. I had to remove both of these manual local repository declarations from `project.clj` files:
   `:local-repo "file:/home/atmamta/.m2/repository/"
   :repositories [["local" "file:/home/atmamta/.m2/repository/"]]`
4. Uninstalled cider snapshot version and its dependent emacs libraries, reinstalled them using the latest stable versions, and modified my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` to reflect these changes. 
   I.e. I changed the `[cider/cider-nrepl "SNAPSHOT-x.y.z"]` line to `[cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.2"]` in `{:user {:plugins ...}}` in file `~/.lein/profiles.clj`
   Important: cider version has to be the same as cider-nrepl version.